# How to assign object values to request model

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

im using mat tab.in this if vailid then retuens values.otherwise return null.and final object values assign to request object ..

```
 saveSettings() {

            if (this.msmsForm.valid) {
                const smsSetting: MasterSMSSetting = {
                    SMSEnabled: this.msmsForm.get('allowOverRide').value,
                    AllowUserOverride: this.msmsForm.get('smsEnabled').value,
                    SMSURL: this.msmsForm.get('smsUrl').value,
                    SMSLogUrl: this.msmsForm.get('smsLogUrl').value,
                    ClientId: this.msmsForm.get('clientId').value,
                    AccesToken: this.msmsForm.get('accessToken').value
                };
            }
            if (this.memailForm.valid) {
            const emailsetting: MasterEmailSetting = {
                SEmailEnabled: this.memailForm.get('allowOverRide').value,
                AllowOverride: this.memailForm.get('emailEnabled').value,
                EmailUrl: this.memailForm.get('emailUrl').value,
                EmailLogUrl: this.memailForm.get('emailLogUrl').value,
                ClientId: this.memailForm.get('clientId').value,
                AccesToken: this.memailForm.get('accessToken').value
            };
        }
            const request: MasterSettingRequest = {
                masterSMS: smsSetting, // getting error "Cannot find name smsSetting'"
                masterEMail: emailsetting, //getting error "Cannot find name smsSetting"
                RequestType: this.requestType
            };


this.mastersettingservice.saveMasterSetting(request).subscribe((response: Response)
```

in this, I wrote if valid.im unable to get those object values due to closed if block!  please let know how to assign those values to a request object

Answer (score 1):

try to use global class variables same as requestType:

```
emailsetting: MasterEmailSetting;
smsSetting: MasterSMSSetting;

saveSettings() {
  if (this.msmsForm.valid) {
    this.smsSetting = {
      SMSEnabled: this.msmsForm.get('allowOverRide').value,
      AllowUserOverride: this.msmsForm.get('smsEnabled').value,
      SMSURL: this.msmsForm.get('smsUrl').value,
      SMSLogUrl: this.msmsForm.get('smsLogUrl').value,
      ClientId: this.msmsForm.get('clientId').value,
      AccesToken: this.msmsForm.get('accessToken').value
    };
  }
  if (this.memailForm.valid) {
    this.emailsetting = {
      SEmailEnabled: this.memailForm.get('allowOverRide').value,
      AllowOverride: this.memailForm.get('emailEnabled').value,
      EmailUrl: this.memailForm.get('emailUrl').value,
      EmailLogUrl: this.memailForm.get('emailLogUrl').value,
      ClientId: this.memailForm.get('clientId').value,
      AccesToken: this.memailForm.get('accessToken').value
    };
  }
  const request: MasterSettingRequest = {
    masterSMS: this.smsSetting,
    masterEMail: this.emailsetting,
    RequestType: this.requestType
  };
  this.mastersettingservice.saveMasterSetting(request).subscribe((response: Response)
```

Comment: thank u fateme fazil ..problem resolved. may i know how to pass null in case form not valid ? using else block ?

Comment: yes try ```emailsetting: MasterEmailSetting= {}``` or null in else.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your solution from below code:

```
saveSettings() {

        if (this.msmsForm.valid) {
            const smsSetting  = {
                SMSEnabled: this.msmsForm.get('allowOverRide').value,
                AllowUserOverride: this.msmsForm.get('smsEnabled').value,
                SMSURL: this.msmsForm.get('smsUrl').value,
                SMSLogUrl: this.msmsForm.get('smsLogUrl').value,
                ClientId: this.msmsForm.get('clientId').value,
                AccesToken: this.msmsForm.get('accessToken').value
            };
        }
        if (this.memailForm.valid) {
            const emailsetting = {
                SEmailEnabled: this.memailForm.get('allowOverRide').value,
                AllowOverride: this.memailForm.get('emailEnabled').value,
                EmailUrl: this.memailForm.get('emailUrl').value,
                EmailLogUrl: this.memailForm.get('emailLogUrl').value,
                ClientId: this.memailForm.get('clientId').value,
                AccesToken: this.memailForm.get('accessToken').value
            };
        }
        const request = {
                masterSMS: smsSetting, // getting error "Cannot find name smsSetting'"
                masterEMail: emailsetting, //getting error "Cannot find name smsSetting"
                RequestType: this.requestType
            };


            this.mastersettingservice.saveMasterSetting(request).subscribe((response: Response)
```